# How can I save the state of a game in python/kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

This is my first question here!
Please forgive my language mistakes, as I am not a native speaker.

I started a month and a half ago programming in python(my first attempt at coding), and now I'm building a game to try to work on a project.

I'm using python and kivy. My game is simply a python version of a DnD style RPG, with a character sheet and (still working on it) a few functions to calculate damage and so on. I figured out how to build windows and import data to the UI, but now I have a couple of problems.

once the values(for example the attack of the character) are imported, I don't seem to be able to change them in kivy. If I press a button that changes the value and I print the new value on the console, I can see it changed, but no on kivy.

Another problem I have is... how can I save the state of the game? once I leave the game all the values and anything I did is, obviously, reset.
I want to be able to make sure that if I add new equipment, fight enemies and the like all the progress is saved. How do I do it?

This is my code so far.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

import Main
from personaggi.Andrea import nomepg




pgnome = str(nomepg.nome)
pgforza = str(nomepg.forza)
pgresistenza = str(nomepg.resistenza)
pgintelligenza = str(nomepg.intelligenza)
pgconcentrazione = str(nomepg.concentrazione)
pgagilita = str(nomepg.agilita)
pgvelocita = str(nomepg.velocita)
pgpersonalita = str(nomepg.personalita)
pgfortuna = str(nomepg.fortuna)



class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass


class CharacterWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass







class GiocoAlpha(App):
    def build(GridLayout):
        pass


    pgnome = pgnome
    pgattacco = pgattacco
    pgforza = pgforza
    pgresistenza = pgresistenza
    pgintelligenza = pgintelligenza
    pgconcentrazione = pgconcentrazione
    pgagilita = pgagilita
    pgvelocita = pgvelocita
    pgpersonalita = pgpersonalita
    pgfortuna = pgfortuna



root = GiocoAlpha()
Window.size = (1000,800)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.run()
```

this is the kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    CharacterWindow:

<LoginWindow>
    name: "loginwindow"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1

            Label:
                text: "Inserire il nome del giocatore"

            TextInput:
                id: nomeplayer
                multiline: False

            Button:
                text: "submit"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "characterwindow"


<CharacterWindow>
    name: "characterwindow"

    GridLayout:



        cols: 3
        rows: 5
        padding: 10

        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            rows: 9
            padding:5
            Label:
                text: "PG: " + app.pgnome
            Label:
                text: "Forza: " + app.pgforza
            Label:
                text: "Resistenza: " + app.pgresistenza
            Label:
                text: "Intelligenza: " + app.pgintelligenza
            Label:
                text: "Concentrazione: " + app.pgconcentrazione
            Label:
                text: "Agilita: " + app.pgagilita
            Label:
                text: "Personalita: " + app.pgpersonalita
            Label:
                text: "Fortuna: " + app.pgfortuna
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 1
            padding:5
            GridLayout:
                cols:1
                rows: 5
                padding:5
                Label:
                    text: "attacco: " + app.pgattacco
                Label:
                    text: "difesa: " + app.pgattacco
                Label:
                    text: "Energia Max: " + app.pgattacco
                Label:
                    text: "Energia: " + app.pgattacco
                Label:
                    text: "Punti Azione Max: " + app.pgattacco

            GridLayout:
                cols:1
                rows: 5
                padding:5
                Label:
                    text: "Punti Azione: " + app.pgattacco
                Label:
                    text: "Volonta: " + app.pgattacco
                Label:
                    text: "Potere: " + app.pgattacco
                Label:
                    text: "Punti Ferita: " + app.pgattacco
                Label:
                    text: "Mana: " + app.pgattacco
            Label:
                text: "Punti Azione Disponibili: "
            Label:
                text: "Volonta': "
```

Comment: Kivy has a [Storage](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-1.10.1/api-kivy.storage.html) module.